# React.js Application deployed with Firebase Hosting without any back end

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, frontend, backend

I would like to build a website using react.js that will be deployed with Firebase Hosting. I am also going to use Firebase Authentication and Real time database It is going to be a dashboard kind of thing where people view some stuff and edit them. I am a bit new to Firebase, and some things are complicated to me.

So, this might sound a bit dumb and I know the answer but is it okay and secure to do it without any back end code? I know that people use Firebase Functions for that but does it make sense to do this without using Functions? I do connect to Firebase Real time database on react frontend. Should I have a backend code that connects to the DB and call that backend to handle all the creating, fetching, editing etc. which I do in frontend at the moment. Is Firebase Authentication enough for me to do all the work in frontend?

Comment: If you set up [firebase database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to control access, and you aren't doing anything fancy, then you may well not need to write any firebase functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @NicholasTower. I see that Firebase Database rules are enough to not use a backend/functions. Could you explain what you mean by fancy?

Comment: Well, anything that can't be achieved by the rules. Sorry if that's vague, but it covers a huge range of possible things. For example, maybe you want to use [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to have different roles for different users. The database rules can *enforce* those roles, but they can't *set* them, so you may need a firebase function to assign roles to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not **need** any backend when running a `Firebase` app if you just want to ensure only `authenticated users` can write to your store. Here are the [Basic Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics)

For `Firestore`, rules go inside the `firestore.rules` file:

```
rules_version = '2';
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

For `Realtime Database`, rules go inside the `database.rules.json` file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside, you can think of Cloud Functions as a simple way to scale your app either physically (region, memory) or in terms of code to separate concerns and make things more readable.

Consider this function which only Firebase authenticated user could call from the React client:

**getChats.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const getChats = functions
.region('us-central1')
.runWith({
  enforceAppCheck: true,
  memory: '256MB',
})
.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  // ensure the user is firebase-authenticated
  if (context.auth == undefined) { // <--- not logged in
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The user must be authenticated.',
    );
  }

  const uuid = context?.auth?.uid as string; // <--- safely cast to string since the user is authed (if using typescript)

  // user is authenticated! continue with database or other logic...
  console.log('data', data); // <--- contains any POST or PUT, etc data

  // finalize the function call
  return Promise.resolve();
});

export default getChats;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer and code snippet. Is it safe to do this in frontend? That is actually what I'm trying to ask. I know it is common practice to have a backend(serverless backend in this case) for security reasons but does Firebase Authentication service provide enough protection and security for me to be able to do all the work(fetching/sending data from/to the Firebase real time database) in the frontend? Do I really need an extra layer(functions) for security? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not *need* a `Cloud function`. When the `Firebase user` is "logged-in" on the frontend, the same user object containing the `uid` is available to you (`context.auth`). Some of the major benefits of `Google Cloud functions` (`Firebase functions`) is you can offload resource-intensive processes or create public APIs etc. As apps grow, functions can help keep things clear. My example is an "Authenticated" function - you can just as easily drop that and make it public using the `.onRequest` method instead which acts more like an Express API. In summary: No, you do not need it for security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and additional example. Your example involves Firestore. It should be possible for Real time DB as well, right? It provides those rules, too.

Comment: For Realtime Database the security rules are slightly different. Revising the answer to include that info --- https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics?authuser=0&hl=en#realtime-database_2